TypeError: Cannot read property Property of undefined with inversify in React Native
General note about my technology: I have an application composed of React Native - Typescript - Inversify - Expo- Expo Router
When I try to inject my class with a constructor, e.g. ILoginUseCaseTwo, and I try to access its login method, I get the error:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'login')

I'll send you some of my files that I think are necessary:
-> inversify.config.ts
import { Container } from 'inversify';
import { ILoginUseCase } from '../domin/usecases/ILoginUseCase';
import { LoginUseCase } from '../domin/usecases/LoginUseCase';
import { TYPES } from './types';
import { ILoginUseCaseTwo } from '../domin/usecases/ILoginTwoUseCase';
import { LoginUseCaseTwo } from '../domin/usecases/LoginUseCaseTwo';
import { TYPESTWO } from './typestwo';

const container = new Container();
container.bind<ILoginUseCase>(TYPES.ILoginUseCase).to(LoginUseCase);
container.bind<ILoginUseCaseTwo>(TYPESTWO.ILoginUseCaseTwo).to(LoginUseCaseTwo);

export { container };

-> types
const TYPES = {
    ILoginUseCase: Symbol.for('ILoginUseCase'),
}

export { TYPES };

-> typestwo
const TYPESTWO = {
    ILoginUseCaseTwo: Symbol.for('ILoginUseCaseTwo'),
}

export { TYPESTWO };

I'm using expo router so I don't have an initial index.ts but rather a _layout
-> package.json
  "main": "expo-router/entry",


import 'reflect-metadata';

import { DarkTheme, DefaultTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import { Stack } from 'expo-router';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useColorScheme } from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-reanimated';

export const unstable_settings = { 
  initialRouteName: '(auth)', 
};

// Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete.
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function RootLayout() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    SpaceMono: require('../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
      <Stack>
        <Stack.Screen name="(auth)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="+not-found" />
      </Stack>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}



I am able to inject into the component if my class does not have a constructor, but if I add the constructor, I get an error.
-> LoginScreen
import { container } from "../../../shared/inversify.config";
import { TYPES } from "../../../shared/types";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { useLoginForm } from "../hooks/useLoginForm";
import LoginView from "../views/LoginView";
import { ILoginUseCase } from "@/src/domin/usecases/ILoginUseCase";

export const LoginScreen = () => {
  const { loginUiState, setUsername, setPassword } = useLoginForm();

  const loginUse = container.get<ILoginUseCase>(TYPES.ILoginUseCase); //aqui ta funcionado aparentemente

  const handleLogin = () => {
    if (loginUse) {
      loginUse.login('ss', 'ss');
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
        <LoginView
            loginUiState={loginUiState}
            actions={{ setUsername, setPassword }}
            onLogin={handleLogin}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

-> login Use Case note: Here the problem begins, if I comment out the constructor and return anything in the return, everything works.
import { inject, injectable } from "inversify";
import { ILoginUseCase } from "./ILoginUseCase";
import { ILoginUseCaseTwo } from "./ILoginTwoUseCase";
import { TYPESTWO } from "../../shared/typestwo";

@injectable()
export class LoginUseCase implements ILoginUseCase {
    constructor(
        @inject(TYPESTWO.ILoginUseCaseTwo) private loginUseCaseTwo: ILoginUseCaseTwo // <- aqui ta o probelma
    ) {}

    async login(username: string, password: string): Promise<boolean> {
        this.loginUseCaseTwo.login(username, password);
        console.log("Login with", username);
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    }
}

Everything is as up to date as possible and recommended. Note: disregard the name of some files, I just put an example like loginUseCaseTwo
My expected behavior should be to normally inject a class into other classes, considering that my inversify-config is defined correctly.

I separated my types because I saw somewhere that it could solve the problem (it didn't work)

I tried toConstructor


